# How to do SSL public key pinning in Alamofire swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift5, public-key-pinning

I am trying to integrate SSL public key pinning in Alamofire swift 5, but I found **`ServerTrustPolicyManager`** which is deprecated. Please help me to integrate. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To integrate SSL public key pinning you first have to add your SSL certificate in your project's target by dragging and dropping it.

To test if your certificate is in the correct format you can try to get the value from `publicKeys` parameter of the `AlamofireExtension` in your main `Bundle`, like this:

```
print("Bundle public keys: \(Bundle.main.af.publicKeys)")
```

If that array have at least one element, then you are ready. If it does not, then try importing your SSL certificate to your Mac's Keychain,  then export it as `.cer` and then add it to your project's target. (this should work)

To check if the public key of the SSL certificate is the one that you import in your project you can use the Alamofire's `ServerTrustManager` with a `PublicKeysTrustEvaluator` instance, when you create your `Session`:

```
let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
    "your.domain.com": PublicKeysTrustEvaluator()
]
let serverTrustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)
let session = Session(serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager)
```

Make sure that in the `evaluators` dictionary, the key (`"your.domain.com"` in the code above) is your servers domain and if you don't want for Alamofire to perform the default validation and/or validate the host you can pass `false` to those parameters in `PublicKeysTrustEvaluator`'s initializer:

```
let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
    "your.domain.com": PublicKeysTrustEvaluator(
        performDefaultValidation: false,
        validateHost: false
    )
]
let serverTrustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)
let session = Session(serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager)
```

Then you have to use this `Session` instance to make any request in your domain, like this:

```
let url = "https://your.domain.com/path/to/api"
session.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseDecodable { response in
    
}
```

As @JonShier pointed out in the comments: You need to keep your `Session` alive beyond the declaring scope. Usually this is done through a single or other outside reference.

Comment: after adding as per your suggestion i am getting **Request failed with error sessionDeinitialized** error. Can you please suggest step by step

Comment: @Bhimashankar in order for this code to work you have to add you SSL certificate in your app's bundle. Did you do that step?

Comment: yes, i added .der certificate file in project bundle. Please explain step by step it will helpful for me to understand. thanks

Comment: You need to keep your `Session` alive beyond the declaring scope. Usually this is done through a single or other outside reference.

Comment: @ gcharita, Jon Shier thanks its working

Comment: How to do this without using the certificate in the Xcode project. As certificate will expire some point of time and in result live app will affect. How to avoid this?

Comment: @shashiGupta `PublicKeysTrustEvaluator` will validate only the public key of the bundled certificate, even if the certificate is expired. You just have to keep the same public key on the subsequent certificate renewals. The bundled certificate does not have to be changed.